# Trying to understand an error with traffic simulation

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, simulation, traffic-simulation

In my code I have the following line

`56 if(0 <= m and m <= 1000): 
---> 57 simulacion[m][p] = 1`

Non the less, I keep having the error

`index -1313 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000`

Clearly m can not be -1313 due to the conditional statement. Does somebody know what is happening? I am using Python 2.7. If extra information is needed, let me know. It is for a traffic simulation project.

Comment: maybe `p` is `-1313`?

Comment: p is obviously the problem, print the value of p before you try to index to confirm. Also you can simplify your expression to `if 0 <= m <= 1000:`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will want to debug what the arguments are when it breaks.
put in a try except block.

```
try:
    simulacion[m][p]=1
except IndexError:  
    print('simulation broke again with an index error')
    print('m is: '+str(m))
    print('p is: '+str(p))
    #possibly more info needed to diagnose the error here
```

Make sure you are keeping limits on 'p' as well as 'm' to make sure m*p stays within the limits of your iterable.